# Autowiring in spring 'byName' not working

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to Spring. Currently starting with xml configuration, so please don't say to use Annotations.
I was reading about autowiring 'byName', and i'm confused on how it works.

My Config file -

```
<bean name="StudentRepositor"
      class="com.sample.Repository.StudentRepositoryHibernate"/>

<bean name="StudentService"
      class="com.sample.Service.StudentServiceQuery" autowire="byName">
      <!--<property name="StudentRepositor" ref="StudentRepositor" />-->
</bean>
```

StudentServiceQuery class-

```
public class StudentServiceQuery implements StudentService {

private StudentRepository studentRepositor;
public void displayList() {

    List<Student> studentList = studentRepositor.returnList();
    System.out.println(studentList.get(0).toString());
}

public void setStudentRepositor(StudentRepository studentRepositor) {
    System.out.println("Dependency Injection - Setter");
    this.studentRepositor = studentRepositor;
}
```

}

Name of the class for bean name "**StudentRepositor**" is "**StudentRepository**"

1. Autowiring works correctly when the bean name is spelled correctly (StudentRepository). The setter method is setStudentRepository, so it calls that for setter injection.
2. When i spell the bean name incorrectly( StudentRepositor ), then if i use property to refer the class, it works. But it fails when i do 'autowiring byName'. The setter method is setStudentRepositor
3. byType autowiring works everytime.

So why autowiring byName fails as mentioned in point 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are declaring a bean :

```
<bean name="StudentRepositor"
      class="com.sample.Repository.StudentRepositoryHibernate"/>
```

The name of bean should not be similar with the name of class it could be any

When you are injecting those declared bean into another one :

```
  <bean name="StudentService"
          class="com.sample.Service.StudentServiceQuery" autowire="byName">
          <property name="StudentRepositor" ref="StudentRepositor" />
    </bean>
```

The ref must be the same you declared bean name section so if the name is StudentRepositor the ref should be the same (StudentRepositor)

For property name when you are injecting it should be the same property name in the class

So if you have such class :

```
public class A{
 private StudentRepositor b;
}
```

The name of property in your xml file should be 'b':

```
 <bean name="StudentService"
              class="com.sample.Service.StudentServiceQuery" autowire="byName">
              <property name="b" ref="StudentRepositor" />
        </bean>
```

Comment: Because property name in your xml file must be the same as in your class

Comment: Same name as my class? Cause the setter function is setStudentRepositor and according to what i read, it looks for setter function only.

Comment: Sorry it should be the same as your property name in your class

Comment: So for example myName in xml file and String myName in your class

Comment: Ok, but then it shouldn't work for 'StudentRepository' also right?( variable is studentRepository  in that case)

Comment: Yes it should not work because it could not find property name StudenRepositor in your class while you have your property named as studendRepositor

Comment: But it works, that's my question. Either none of them should work, or both should work

Comment: It’s fine because you are telling ref bean name StudentRepositor as it’s defined in <bean name =“StudentRepositor”/> but when setting property name it should be the same as property name in xml

Comment: You need to declare ref not with class of bean but with name which you defined to it

Comment: bean name should not be the same as name of your class it could be any for example myBean and then in bean ref you need to use this name as myBean

Comment: Please ask a question if you don’t understood

Comment: @Mykhaklio Can you write an Answer to summarise all your comments please. I still having hard time to understand your explanations

Comment: also you have commented property in you config

Comment: Do you have additional questions, please ask